# Rails order by count on association

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have 2 models. `Gif, GifStatistic`

```
gif has_many :gif_statistics
```

`GifStatistics` has column called `state`. It can be either `like` or `dislike`

What i want to achieve is to query gifs, but order them in `highest count of likes`

Something like(Pseudo code)

```
Gif.joins(:gif_statistics).order(count(gif.gif_statistics.state))
```

How do i achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query.

```
Gif.joins(:gif_statistics).select("*, count(gif_statistics.state) as state_count").order("state_count desc")
```

My personal recommendation is that you create two new fields in the gif model so that you can store the count of like and dislike as and when its created so that you don't have to do such a complex query. Placing the counter cache would improve the speed.

Comment: well, i did simplier way - added column with counts i needed

Comment: How is this ordering by likes only?  It seems to be counting all `GifStatistics`.